# Need some help with matlab syntax for logical equivalence/inference

Tags: logic, matlab

I've got a maths question that I need to translate into matlab syntax to run through and I'm slightly stuck so hopefully someone here can help since I can't seem to find my answer online.

The equation is as follows: (¬p ∧ q) ∧ (r → p) ∧ (¬r → s) ∧ (s → t) ⇒ t

So far, in matlab I have:

```
(~p(1) & p(2)) & (p(3) <= p(1)) & (~p(3) <= p(4)) & (p(4) <= p(5))
```

But I'm not sure how to input the ⇒ t

Can anyone help me with the syntax for the arrow?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well I played around in matlab a little more and realised that:

→ and ⇒

have exactly the same matlab syntax:

```
<=
```

But I'll leave this up here for other people :)

Comment: By the way, do you realize why it's "<="? It's because $0,1$ are used to represent $false,true$.